# Laravel-5.5: How to write correct path to image in html code using css?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-5.5

I use method `asset()` for connect assets to website. Example:

```
<link href="{{ asset('dist/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And how I can use method `asset()` in this html code for include images using css:

```
<div class="attached-img-container" style="background-image:url(dist/img/gallery/equal-size/mock1.jpg)"></div>
```

List of my routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'inbox', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'InboxController@index',])->name('inbox');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/message/{id?}', ['uses'=>'InboxController@message'])->name('message');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/compose', ['uses'=>'InboxController@compose'])->name('compose');
});
```

In route `inbox` assets work from public folder but in `message` or in `compose` routes assets not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
background-image:url({{ asset('dist/img/gallery/equal-size/mock1.jpg') }})
```

That being said, if the `dist` directory is in your public folder, you should be able to add `/` at the beginning:

```
background-image:url(/dist/img/gallery/equal-size/mock1.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path like this:

```
background-image:url(/dist/img/gallery/equal-size/mock1.jpg)
```

Comment: image in public folder but if I create group of routes with in prefix then assets not working @Marcin

Comment: If that's the problem, you should include your routes

Comment: How I must include my routes?

Comment: Add them into your question

Answer (score 0):

no need to use `asset()` if it is inside `public folder` , you can directly access it by using `/`

for example your image is inside `public/images/myimage.jpg`

then u can use `<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" />`

```
<div style="background-url:('/images/myimage.jpg')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `url()` helper function like-

```
background-image:url({{ url('/dist/img/gallery/equal-size/mock1.jpg') }})
```